# The use of "among" in subject construction

Tags: phrases

I came across the following sentence in the newspaper yesterday: *"Among the questions is who fired the fatal shots that killed nine."*

This construction just doesn't seem right to me. Is there some case in which a prepositional phrase such as *"Among the questions"* can be used as a subject?

Best,

Doug

Answer (score 1):

"Among the questions" is not the subject.  The subject is "who fired the fatal shots that killed nine".  The example sentence is an inversion of "Who fired the fatal shots that killed nine is among the questions".

Comment: As evidenced by `is`, which isn't agreeing with `questions`. Upvoted.

Comment: Despite the sentence structure being "inverted," Isn't "among the questions" still a prepositional phrase? And if so, how can it function as an object - linked by "is?" - Doug

Comment: "is" does not take a following direct object.  Among the complements it does take are prepositional phrases, which will be obvious to you if you just experiment with a few examples.